# Passing PHP's _server to python CLI program as a dict

Tags: php, python

I am trying to call a python command-line (CLI) from a PHP program. As part of that, I have to pass in the _server array from the PHP program to the python program. From the python side, a dict seems like an appropriate data structure. However, what is the best way to pass a variable length _server array to python?

Also, do I need to worry about encoding, so should I wrap _server into a json object?

Any thoughts or ideas are much appreciated.

References:
PHP's _server array http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: surely python has an equivalent of the php $_SERVER array?

Comment: It does, though I have to find a way of passing it from PHP since the original program is in PHP.

Comment: but its running on the same server as the php script so the vars will be the same so, what's the point?

Comment: Because the new process that is the python script runs it won't inherit the _server or any other variable from the php script. Have to pass it in via command line parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Pass it as JSON, and decode it in the python program.

Example:

```
exec('/path/to/your/python/program ' . escapeshellarg(json_encode($_SERVER)));
```

Comment: This. You have two completely different environments and the only well-supported common data formats between them are XML (blech!) and JSON. If it's a *lot* of data you could write it to `/tmp/something.json` and pass the file name.